# Appending different sized nd arrays into a single array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, valueerror

I have a multi-dimensional array of 5000*3072 which I divided into 5 chunks of 1000*3072 using

```
numpy.array_split()
```

function. Now for iteration, I need to combine different combinations of the array

```
For example, 0th iteration: 1,2,3,4 chunks to combine
             1st iteration: 0,2,3,4 chunks to combine
             2nd iteration: 0,1,3,4 chunks to combine and so on
```

I tried to do using `np.concatenate` but it gives the error:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Is there any other way of this combination?

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].

Comment: I hope you wanted to do the concatenation along `axis 0`. Also, it's interesting to know why do you want to try out such a problem.. may be you want to jumble the rows to produce an *adversarial grayscale image*, if we treat the input array as an image ;)

Comment: What are the array shapes that you tried to concatenate?  What exactly was concatenation expression?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) like

```
In [10]: arr = np.arange(20).reshape((5,4))

# split `arr` into 5 sub-arrays
In [11]: split_arrs = np.array_split(arr, 5)

# concatenate only last four sub-arrays
# for your case: 1,2,3,4 chunks to combine
In [12]: np.concatenate(split_arrs[1:], axis=0)
Out[12]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])


# 0,2,3,4 chunks to combine
In [15]: np.concatenate((split_arrs[0], *split_arrs[2:]), axis=0)
Out[15]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])

# 0,1,3,4 chunks to combine
In [16]: np.concatenate((*split_arrs[0:2], *split_arrs[3:]), axis=0)
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

---

I think you got the `ValueError` because you might have done something like:

```
In [17]: np.concatenate((split_arrs[0], split_arrs[2:]), axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-938d5afdd06a> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((split_arrs[0], split_arrs[2:]), axis=0)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Note that if you're passing the sub-arrays in a tuple, then you should *unpack* it so that the dimensions match.